# What is my version of LLVM & clang (OSX)?

Tags: c++, macos, clang, llvm, c++14

On Mac OS, if I run `clang --version`, I get:

```
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.34.4) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Since [LLVM official page](http://llvm.org) suggests that the current LLVM version is 3.5, it seems that Apple clang versioning is distinct from the open-source LLVM. The output `(based on LLVM 3.5svn)` suggests that probably it is 3.5 on my machine as well.

Now I got here since I wanted to compile a C++14 file, using `g++ -std=c++14 main.cc`. [This page](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) suggests that this option should work on clang 3.5. However, it works only with `-std=c++1y`, which works on clang 3.4 or earlier.

So what is LLVM open-source version equivalent for Apple's version? It seems 3.5 but then why it doesn't work so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is some Version of the llvm 3.5 svn branch before the official 3.5 release version.

Meaning that it probably should have all features of 3.4 plus some of the 3.5 features.