# How does Apple clang-703.0.29 map back to clang releases in terms of C++1x support?

Tags: c++11, clang, xcode7, c++14

I want to map Apple's clang which is shipped with Xcode back to the official clang feature list.

But I couldn't link the two. The version is obscured.

Is there a way to tell?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421690/what-is-my-version-of-llvm-clang-osx

Comment: Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32985758/what-is-the-llvm-version-bundled-with-xcode-7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't quite understand why would you need such information, since [they already claim full compatibility with C++11 spec](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html).

Anyway, here's my take on it.

Please note that following steps will not reveal a clear answer but currently I can't think of a better approach to this.

1. [This developer curated list](https://gist.github.com/yamaya/2924292) suggests that `Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 clang 703.0.29` is bundled with `Xcode 7.3 (7D175)`.
2. When I go to [the project page for clang in Apple Open Source website](https://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/), unfortunately I can't see a directory for `703.0.29` build. **Not yet at least**.
3. Whenever they release it, get it.
4. Also, get official `clang`'s trunk from http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/
5. [Run tests](http://clang.llvm.org/hacking.html#testing) named `$OFFICIAL_CLANG_ROOT/test/SemaCXX/cxx11*.cpp` over Apple's `clang`.
6. Evaluate

Comment: Perfect answer.  Thank you.