# Multiple variable initialization compiler support

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, initialization

Under g++ 7.4 I could declare and initialize multiple variables like so:

```
std::pair<T, T> foo();

int main ()
{  auto [a, b] = foo();  }
```

However under Apple clang-703 it gives me an error.

I could not find any information about support for this feature in both compilers. Is it supported by modern compilers or should I not use it? Also what is the name of the feature?

Edit:
The error is:

```
auto [a, b] = foo();
      ^1    ^2
```

1 => use of undeclared identifier 'a'.

2 => expected unqualified-id.

Comment: @bstract_Everything It is called  structured binding declarations and is supported by compilers that confirm to C++ 17.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ok so it is standardized. If you post as an answer Ill mark it.

Comment: What is the error? Clang 7 supports structured bindings.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a C++17 feature called a **[structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)**.

[Clang 5 supports them](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80ba21ba98a4110a); in fact [it did since 4, as do many other compilers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support).

Trouble is, you're using Apple Clang, which has [different version numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36212191/560648). Possibly your compiler is just too old, or you did not enable C++17 functionality the way you did with your GCC 7.4 (in which C++17 was still experimental and opt-in).

Comment: Thanks did not know about the different versions, I had 17 enabled since I built it from cmake. I cannot upvote the answer due to reputation.

Comment: Now you can! ;)